# asp.net website when chance in css style and debug doesn't reflect

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I have a asp.net website I made change to the css style sheet when looking at design view i can see the change have been done but when I debug it is not the same ?

Comment: Are you sure about the CSS rules you have been using ? Nothing overrides them ?

Comment: use firefox and install a plugin call clear cache to clean your cache.

Comment: I use Firefox with the dev toolbar to have a REALLY easy way to disable the cache when I think that is the issue.

Answer (score 2):

After you debug press `ctrl + F5` on your browser that will probably reflect your `css` changes

You will find more about [Clear Your Browser's Cache](http://www.wikihow.com/Clear-Your-Browser%27s-Cache) here

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use the browsers built in tools for inspecting HTML elements and then check to see if the specified CSS rule that you changed has been applied. My guess is that your browser cached the previous look of the page but I might be off on that. In any case 1st check if the CSS change was actually applied then proceed from there...